# Gatsby - Possible to create a standalone page within site?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Is there a suggested way to create a "standalone" page within a larger Gatsby site? Not sure if I am describing it correctly...

I have a route/page that requires some heavy use of 3rd party js libraries that seem to conflict with other areas of my Gatsby site. I am trying to just isolate that page and force a page navigate to that particular page without any single page app functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place files in the `static` folder and they'll be copied over to the `public` folder on build, so creating a file at `static/some-page/index.html` would wind up available at `https://www.example.com/some-page/` and wouldn't load any Gatsby-related code.